# Rescue 403 forbidden images in views from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I want to rescue every 403 response from S3 in my app. They're mostly in image tags, breaking the image in the view. How can I do that in `ApplicationController` when the image tags don't raise exceptions, they just have broken images in the view?

```
rescue_from ??? do |e|
  logger.debug "broken image: #{e}"
end
```

Some images are rendered in a helper like so:

```
def user_image(img_style)
 "<img src='#{asset.image(img_style)}' />"
end
```

Where `asset.image(img_style)` returns a (in this case forbidden) URL.

Others are just like:

```
<%= image_tag document.other_asset.image(:small) %>
```

There's no single parent controller (save `ApplicationController`) I guess.

There is, however, a single polymorphic class (`ImageAttachment`) that stores the image. Should I fetch it in the model beforehand and raise the error? Doesn't that involve making the request twice?

Comment: Can we see how you are loading the images, and what your controller looks like?

Comment: There's nothing non-standard there. I'm also talking system-wide, not just under a particular controller. Some are rendered directly into image tags, which I'll show, and others just in the view with an `image_tag`.

Comment: Exactly what @GarrettMotzner said, we need some more context on how you're loading images. You probably need to check the HTTP response code from the S3 request. A HTTP status code of `403` wouldn't directly raise an error in your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is **absolutely horrible** and doubles the number of requests per image, but for completion's sake:

```
def found?(style = :small)
  return true if URI.open(image(style))
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => exception
  logger.debug exception.message
  false
end
```

A better implementation obviously is in Javascript so resources don't have to be loaded twice, but since the question started with Ruby it'll end there, too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images